# PiTFT - See Previous Image Behind Next Image

Tags: pitft

I purchased a [PiTFT](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1601) from AdaFruit. I'm drawing directly to the screen by memory mapping /dev/fb1 and that is working.

The problem happens when I update the screen with the color white. I can see faded remnants of the previous image in the new white image. Eventually the previous image fades out entirely and then I see a solid white image. I've tried blanking the previous image with black before drawing white, but that did not solve the problem.

Is there way to work around this problem or is it a limitation of the display? It's fairly noticeable, so I would like to clean it up if possible.

Comment: I've noticed this on other tft screens, like my phone. Opening blank image leaves faded stuff of the last one. TFTs seem to have this issue.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder why TFT screens behave like that.  Most of the search results I found talked about burn-in, but that is not the case here.